# I have some VBA that opens a spreadsheet and imports data from Access, how do I lock the original and automatically "Save As"?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, database-administration

The code below is attached to a command button and opens an Excel Workbook then imports a dozen (mostly redacted in code below) fields from an Access Form. The trouble I have is that users:

(1) Use the button once.

(2) Hit "Save" instead of "Save As".

(3) Use the button a second time.

(3) Complain that the workbook has old data on it.

Within the code below, how can I:

(A) Prevent users from editing the master copy of the workbook.

(B) Automatically present the "Save As" dialogue box upon opening.

```
Private Sub cmd1_Click()
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim wbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
appExcel.Visible = True
Set wbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("F:\Network Folder\MySpreadsheet.xlsx")
Set wsheet = wbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With wsheet
.Cells(10, 1).Value = txt1
.Cells(10, 2).Value = txt2   
End With
End Sub
```

I've tried the solutions offered [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/80796-how-set-readonly-visual-basic-applications.html) but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set wbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="F:\Network Folder\MySpreadsheet.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
```